# Cannot find symbol class window error in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I'm pretty new to Java and jsp and I was searching for a way to redirect to a new page. I found I can do that by using

```
window.location.href="<relative location>";
```

I'm using NetBeans and I have included it into my jsp page within the <% %> part and it asks me to import a package namely "*java.awt.SystemColor.window*"

It does include the following line automatically when I select it:

```
<%@page import="java.awt.SystemColor.window" %>
```

But it still gives me an error saying

> error: cannot find symbol
>   import java.awt.SystemColor.window;
>     symbol:   class window
>     location: class SystemColor

I've been searching on stackoverflow and other places as well but haven't found anything to resolve it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to import anything.Just assign the url to window.location.href inside the script tag.
Eg
window.location="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/accessDeniedAction.action";

Comment: This is what I have currently 
`<%
        if(userValidation.isLoggedIn() != true){
                window.location.replace("../");
                out.println("NO GO");
            }
        %> `
and it shows package window not found.

Comment: use window.location outside the scripts.                                                               eg: <% if(userValidation.isLoggedIn() != true){%> window.location.replace("../");<% out.println("NO GO"); } %>

Answer (score 0):

`window` is a JavaScript object not java object. So you should write `window.location.replace("../");` outside the scriplet

example

```
 <% if(userValidation.isLoggedIn() != true){ 
%>window.location.replace("../"); <%out.println("NO GO"); } %>
```

**Note:** use of scriplets is highly discouraged. Please use JSTL